# How run own psm1 file remotely?

Tags: powershell

I have a psm1 file in my local windows and I want run this file on another computer remotely. because I have some function in this psm1 file and I have to execute this function on remote computer from local computer. 
I create psm1 file in each computer locally and use invoke-command for execute my function but I have some error that cant find my function. I check execution-policy in both system is unrestricted. I change it to remoting but I have had same error.

I use this code for uses remote function :

$rdata = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername {param($remote_Logs)
          CheckEventLog -EventLogs  $remote_Logs} -ArgumentList $Logs
how can i do?

Comment: Can you provide us more information? What error do you retrieve? What kind of function do you want to invoke?

Comment: CheckEventLog  is a custome Function that i create it. It get some information about logs from event viwer. and I take error about the smdlet can't find function CheckEventLog into remote computer. but I craete this function on the remote computer and this function run localy true.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I create new session and Invoke my command with session.

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'server1'

$rdata = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($module_path,$remote_Logs)
           Import-Module $module_path
           CheckEventLogDetails -EventLogs  $remote_Logs}  -ArgumentList $modulepath,$Logs